# Segmentation fault when initializing struct w/ arrays

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm writing an ncurses Scrabble clone in C.

I've written some code to represent a bag, which is a source of shuffled characters that you can pull characters out of, much like pulling random tiles out of a bag in real life.

My code works on OS X - but when I try to compile on a Debian machine, it gives me this blunt message:

```
~/nscrabble $ ./scrabble
Segmentation fault
```

I've used `gdb` to try to diagnose the problem. It appears that the segfault was caused on the `return` statement:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jay/nscrabble/scrabble 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400ca8 in bag () at bag.c:53
53          return b;
(gdb)
```

There you go. Here's the code (both `bag.c` and `bag.h`)
Here's `bag.h` --

```
#ifndef BAG_H_INCLUDED
#define BAG_H_INCLUDED

/*
 * This array states how many times each
 * letter should show up in the bag.
 *
 * distributions[0]     Number of As
 * distributions[1]     Number of Bs
 * ...
 * distributions[25]    Number of Zs
 * distributions[26]    Number of blank tiles
 */
const short distributions[27];

/*
 * The bag is the repository of tiles in Scrabble.
 * I didn't want to deal with storing pointers
 * and freeing them constantly, so I decided to
 * store chars.
 */
typedef struct bag {
        char tiles[100];
        size_t top;

        /*
         * Get a tile letter out of the bag.
         * It removes the letter from the bag.
         */
        char (*pop)( struct bag* );
} bag_t;

/*
 * The constructor.
 * Get a new bag using this.
 */
struct bag bag();



char bg_pop( struct bag* );

#endif
```

And here's `bag.c` --

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "bag.h"

const short distributions[27] = {
        9, 2, 2, 4, 12, 2, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 2, 1, 
        6, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2
};

char bg_pop( struct bag* b )
{
        return b->tiles[b->top--];
}

struct bag bag()
{
        struct bag b;
        for( char letter = 'A', count = 0; letter <= ']'; letter++ ) {
                for(int i = 0; i < distributions[letter - 65]; i++, count++)
                        b.tiles[count] = letter;
        }
        srand( time(NULL) );
        for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++, rand() )
                ;
        for( int i = 0; i < 98; i++ ) {
                int n = (rand() % (100 - i)) + i;
                char temp = b.tiles[i];
                b.tiles[i] = b.tiles[n];
                b.tiles[n] = temp;
        }
        b.top = 100;
        b.pop = bg_pop;
        return b;
}
```

scrabble.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bag.h"

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
        struct bag b = bag();

        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
                printf("%3c", b.tiles[i]);
}
```

I know that the shuffling is being done correctly (at least on OS X).

Could someone please help shed some light as to what is happening here?

Comment: are you getting this to compile?

Comment: Yes, it compiles. I should show the `scrabble.c` file, though, that contains the main function. 1 sec.

Comment: Your error message refers to line 53 of `bag.c`, but the `bag.c` you posted doesn't contain that many lines.

Comment: `return b->tiles[b->top--];`. Since `b->top` is initialised to `100` and the `tiles` array is sized at `100` it appears that would cause an overflow. Also, it's unlikely that the `return` is causing the seg fault. Perhaps you have a code mismatch or some other gdb quirk in play.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I am so mindless! The original code has the GPL thing at the top. The line mentioned is the one with `return b` in the bag() method

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for the advice! I changed `top` to 99 but the segfault's still there :/

Comment: The full code is at https://backtick.town/~jay/nscrabble/ if anyone wants it

Comment: @stanpines: I just compiled and ran it on Debian Linux, and it didn't segfault for me.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Are you compiling the whole thing, or just the three? Did you make any modifications?

Comment: @stanpines: Just the code you posted in your question. And yes, I did make one modification after a compiler warning. I changed `char letter = 'A'` to `int letter = 'A'`. If I change it back it segfaults. There's your problem.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thanks! It works now. It must be something with `char`'s range being too small, yeah?

Comment: @stanpines: Yes, but only incidentally. There's something wrong with your loop logic, and how you're using `count`. If you print out the value at the end of each outer loop you'll see that it goes way over 100, so you're going out-of-bounds on your array by miles. It's still an error when you change it to `int`, just not one that makes you segfault in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
for( char letter = 'A', count = 0; letter <= ']'; letter++ ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < distributions[ letter - 65 ]; i++, count++ ) {
        b.tiles[count] = letter;
    }
}
```

if you print out the value of `count` you'll see that it gets as high as 152, way higher than the 100 elements in your array. You seem to be segfaulting because this will make `count` go negative on your system, as you've defined it as a `char`, which is signed on your system.

You can define it as an `int` and the segfault goes away for me when I do, but you're still going way out of bounds on your array, so there's clearly something wrong with your logic in using `count`, here. Or, more usefully, you've got a pair of loops which spit out 152 letters, but you've only set aside memory for 100 of them, so you're making more letters than you have space for.

If you change `letter <= ']'` to `letter <= '['` (since `'['` comes immediately after `'Z'` in the ASCII table) then your loop correctly quits once `count` reaches 100, and you should be set.

Comment: Also, distributions has 27 slots, but to accommodate 'A' through ']', you need 29.

Comment: @jszakmeister: You're right, probably it should be `'['` rather than `']'`.

Comment: @jszakmeister distributions looks like it's working fine - I did some tweaking and `[` shows up twice in the array, like it's supposed to. It's an ASCII table "hack"

Comment: But yes, I fixed that thing in the loop

Comment: @stanpines: It probably only works "like it's supposed to" because those extra characters only appear among the ones that shoot past the end of your array.

Comment: Ah. I changed `letter <= ']'` to `letter <= '['`. I also added a ` || count < 100`

Comment: @stanpines: Answer updated. Turns out if you change to `'['` then your loops stop when `count` gets to 100, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the bounds of your array at line 21:

```
b.tiles[count] = letter;
```

To see this with gdb:

```
gdb blah
b 21
cond 1 count >= 100
run
```

If you go high enough with `count` above, you'll trash the return address on the stack and that's why you segfault on the `return`